# Функция при клике на select, подогнать значение второго селекта к 1-му (через индекс)?

Tags: javascript

Прошу чистый js. Есть 2 селекта, как сделать так чтобы при выборе одного селекта во 2-й автоматически подставлялось значение того же индекса, см.

```
<form name="myform">
    <select name="mysel1" style="width: 135px; onchange="onSel(this.form.mysel1)"">
        <option value="uno">uno</option>
        <option value="duo">duo</option>
        <option value="tre">tre</option>
</select><br />
    <select name="mysel2" style="width: 135px; onchange="onSel(this.form.mysel2)"">
        <option value="unos">unos</option>
        <option value="dos">dos</option>
        <option value="tres">tres</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

объясняю: выбрали duo (1-ый select), в 2-м селекте подставилось dos, если выбрали допустим tres (2-ой select), то в 1-м селекте выбралось tre. Ориентироваться по индексам!

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stasonix/h2nMW/1/)

половина получилась:

```
function onSel(dropdown){

selIndx = dropdown.selectedIndex;

  switch(dropdown.name)
  {
      case 'mysel1': document.form.mysel2.options[selIndx].selected == true;
      break;
      case 'mysel2': document.form.mysel1.options[selIndx].selected == true;
      break;
  }

}
```

увы, ошибку вешает, не может найти такой select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/h2nMW/3/. Не **form**, а **myform**. Не **selected == true**, а **selected = true**

```
function onSel(dropdown){

selIndx = dropdown.selectedIndex;

  switch(dropdown.name)
  {
      case 'mysel1': document.myform.mysel2.options[selIndx].selected = true;
      break;
      case 'mysel2': document.myform.mysel1.options[selIndx].selected = true;
      break;
  }

}
```

или

```
// ...
document.myform.mysel2.options[selIndx].selected = 'selected';
// ...
```

Comment: ой, да, спасибо, начудил немножко с ==.